# How to open menu with hover in Next.js css module?

Tags: javascript, html, css, next.js, css-modules

This is the element in the navbar:

```js
<div className={styles.menu}>
  <button
    className={"a_4"}
    style={{
      color: "white",
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
      borderWidth: "0px",
      cursor: "pointer",
    }}
  >
    {userName}
  </button>
  <Menu />
</div>
```

I have a style for it, to handle hover:

```css
.menu:hover .menuContainer {
  display: block;
}
```

and here is have the `<Menu>`

```
function Menu() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  return (
    <div className={styles.menuContainer}>
      <ul>
        <li className={styles.menuItem}>
          <Link href={"/hu"}>
            <a className={"a_5"}>Profil</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
```

The problem, hover not open menu. Why? How to fix?

Menu container normally is invisible:

```
.menuContainer {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
```